# How can I draw a circle with Clutter?

Tags: clutter

I want to draw a circle with clutter but I am unable to figure how can I do that. I am using clutter with vala programming language but an example in c would be sufficient also in case you don't know vala. So how can i do that ?

Answer (score 3):

you can use ClutterCairoTexture, and draw the circle using the Cairo API, if you want to have high-quality, 2D drawing.